# ASP, DropDownList grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I'm new to `ASP MVC`. I want to load data from a database in [DropDownList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js737.png) into a `gridview`. But DATA cannot load.

**HTML CODE**

```
              <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Code">
                <HeaderStyle Width="106px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1" />
                <ItemStyle Width="102px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Nom Cours">
                <HeaderStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="left" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1" />
                <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="left" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>



            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Prix / Heure (HTG)">
            <HeaderStyle Width="160px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1" />
            <ItemStyle Width="160px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderWidth="1px" />
                <itemtemplate>     
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlprice" Width="160px" HorizontalAlign="center"  runat="server">

                    </asp:DropDownList>                         
              </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>          


             <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Sélectionner">
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1" />
                  <ItemStyle Width="300px" HorizontalAlign="center" BorderWidth="1px" />
                <itemtemplate> 
             <asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect" CssClass="gridCB"  runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center"></asp:checkbox>                
              </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" Height="30px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Navy" Font-Bold="True" Height="22px" HorizontalAlign="Left"
            ForeColor="WhiteSmoke" BorderColor="Navy" VerticalAlign="Top" BorderWidth="2px" Width="910px" Font-Size="Small" />
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="SkyBlue" ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle Height="5px" Font-Size="Smaller" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Aquamarine" ForeColor="GhostWhite" BorderColor="Silver"
            BorderStyle="None" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="SkyBlue" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

**C# CODE**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlClassroom.SelectedValue = "-1";

            BindDataGridClass();
            BindDataGridCourse();
            loadListPrice();
        }

private void loadListPrice()
    {
        List<Course> listPrice = Course.getListCoursePriceOrdered();
        ddlprice.DataValueField = "id";
        ddlprice.DataTextField = "price";
        ddlprice.DataSource = listPrice;
        ddlprice.DataBind();
        //ddlprice.Items.Insert(0, new DropDownListItem("--Selectionner--", "-1"));
        ddlprice.SelectedValue = "0";

    }
```

Comment: Please add proper description of the code.

Comment: This is all web forms code and has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

First add the `OnRowDataBound` event to the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

Then in code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //find the dropdownlist in the row with findcontrol and cast it back to one
        DropDownList ddlprice = e.Row.FindControl("ddlprice") as DropDownList;

        //you now have access to all the dropdownlist properties
        ddlprice.DataSource = Course.getListCoursePriceOrdered();
        ddlprice.DataValueField = "id";
        ddlprice.DataTextField = "price";
        ddlprice.DataBind();
        ddlprice.SelectedValue = "0";
    }
}
```